# Exclude tables in show tables like statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

In `MySQL` database I have some tables which end with `_history`.

Now I want to select tables that are like `_history`.

I have done like below.

```
show tables like '%_history`
```

Now I got the desired result.

Now in this result I got some tables which start with `temp`. Ex: `temp_102_history`.

Is there a way to exclude the tables that start with `temp` in the `show tables like '%_history` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Select table_name
    from information_schema.tables
     Where table_name like '%_history'
 and table_name not like 'temp%' 
and table_schema='your database'
```

You can use `information_schema` database for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SHOW TABLES 
      WHERE tables_in_test NOT LIKE 'temp_%' 
        AND tables_in_test LIKE '%_history'
```

Replace test with your DB name.

Comment: This answer, while possibly locale-dependent, is the simpler and clearer answer, and works just fine. I downvoted it because I mis-typed (I put quotes around 'tables_in_test'), and S.O. has this crazy "nobody makes errors they need to correct more than 5 minutes later" policy with comments and votes, so now the vote's stuck. Mea culpa :(